# Get NSString from NSMutableArray on Swift

Tags: swift, nsmutablearray

How can I get NSString from NSMutableArray created with NSStrings in a for loop? I want to store in one NSString, all elements of NSMutableArray. This is my code:

```
class Persona: NSObject {

    var edad: Int
    var altura: Double
    var nombre: NSString
    var apellido: NSString
    var cualidades: NSMutableArray

    init(edad:Int, altura:Double, nombre:NSString, apellido:NSString, cualidades:NSMutableArray){
        self.edad = edad
        self.altura = altura
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellido = apellido
        self.cualidades = cualidades
    }

    func addCualidad(cualidad:NSString){
        cualidades.addObject(cualidad)
    }

    func delCualidad(cualidad:NSString){
        cualidades.removeObject(cualidad)
    }

    func cualidadesToString() -> NSString{
        var string:NSString = ""
        for cualidad in cualidades{

            // TODO HERE
            cualidad...

        }
        return cualidad
    }

}
```

As you can see I want NSString returned in cualidadesToString() method.

Comment: Do you want to concatenate a long string of the elements in your array? I'm a little confused of your end goal.

Comment: @JustinRose My end goal is store all elements in NSMutableArray called "cualidades" in NSString called "cualidad" and return that in cualidadesToString() method.

Comment: `componentsJoinedByString` is probably what you are looking for. – Also consider to use Swift's native `String` and `Array` instead of the Foundation types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `componentsJoinedByString`

```
func cualidadesToString() -> NSString{
    return cualidades.componentsJoinedByString(",")
}
```

But you should use Swift's builtin String and Array types to make it more type-safe.

```
var cualidades = [String]()

func addCualidad(cualidad: String){
    cualidades.append(cualidad)
}

func delCualidad(cualidad: String){
    if let cindex = find(cualidades, cualidad) {
        cualidades.removeAtIndex(cindex)
    }
}

func cualidadesToString() -> String{
    return join(", ", cualidades)
}
```